# vb.net autocomplete with delimiters

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete

I've seen several similar older questions but none of them was properly answered, so I'm raising the topic again. What I need is easy: I have a list of strings composed of one or severals words each (in that case separated by ","). I want a textbox to suggest one or more of those strings when the user is typing, but taking into account not only the first word of the string, but also the others. As a silly example, if my string list is:

- string 1: bike, redish
- string 2: car, red
- string 3: cat, brown

When the user types: "b" strings 1 and 3 should be suggested (bike and brown), when the user types "c" or "ca" strings 2 and 3 should be suggested (car and cat).

So far, I got the autocomplete property working but only for the first word (so if my user types "b" only string 1 will be suggested). This is the code:

```
Dim newstr As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
While dr.Read 'this is a datareader from which I get my list
   newstr.Add(dr.Item(0).ToString)
End While
dr.Close()
mytextbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
mytextbox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
mytextbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = newstr
```

How can I achieve what I need? I thought it would be already implemented, but it seems not. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You'll have to find an existing one and include it into your project, or build your own. Default autocompletion behaviour only checks from the start

Comment: I'd tried to find one, but no luck so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think an autocomplete source is what you want for this.

Instead I suggest you use a ComboBox in DropDown mode.

```
ComboBox3.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
```

You need to make the list part visible when the control gets focus...

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.GotFocus
    ComboBox3.DroppedDown = True
End Sub
```

Then rebuild the list contents based on whenever the textbox changes.

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.KeyUp
    Dim Ss = ComboBox3.SelectionStart 
    Dim Sl = ComboBox3.SelectionLength

.... rebuilt the list items here ...

    Dim Ss = ComboBox3.SelectionStart 
    Dim Sl = ComboBox3.SelectionLength
    ComboBox3.DroppedDown = True
End Sub
```

**COMPLETE EXAMPLE**

```
Public Class Form4
Dim employees() As String = New String() {"Hamilton, David", _
      "Hensien, Kari", "Hammond, Maria", "Harris, Keith", _
      "Henshaw, Jeff D.", "Hanson, Mark", "Harnpadoungsataya, Sariya", _
      "Harrington, Mark", "Harris, Keith", "Hartwig, Doris", _
      "Harui, Roger", "Hassall, Mark", "Hasselberg, Jonas", _
      "Harnpadoungsataya, Sariya", "Henshaw, Jeff D.", "Henshaw, Jeff D.", _
      "Hensien, Kari", "Harris, Keith", "Henshaw, Jeff D.", _
      "Hensien, Kari", "Hasselberg, Jonas", "Harrington, Mark", _
      "Hedlund, Magnus", "Hay, Jeff", "Heidepriem, Brandon D."}

Private Sub ComboBox3_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.GotFocus
    ComboBox3.DroppedDown = True
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.KeyUp

    Dim Ss = ComboBox3.SelectionStart ' + 1

    ComboBox3.Items.Clear()

    Dim SearchText As String = UCase(ComboBox3.Text)
    For Each Str As String In employees
        Dim UStr As String = UCase(Str)
        If InStr(UStr, SearchText) = 1 OrElse InStr(UStr, " " & SearchText) > 0 Then
            ComboBox3.Items.Add(Str)
        End If

    Next
    ComboBox3.SelectionStart = Ss
    ComboBox3.SelectionLength = 0
    ComboBox3.DroppedDown = True
End Sub
End Class
```

**MAKE SURE you set the comboboxstyle to DropDown**

[image]

Comment: Could you please show me a simple example? I tried to follow your scheme but it is not working. As soon as I filter the list items, the first of them gets selected (overwriting what the user was typing). Thanks!

Comment: awesome, thanks! It seems the key was in the Items.Clear() method